# Working with karma and BrowserStack

Tags: karma-runner, browserstack

I'm currently working with Karma(0.12.33) with Karma-browserstack-launcher(0.1.2), As I set up my username and accessKey, it keeps telling me `Starting browser iPhone 6 (ios 6.0) on BrowserStack` without running test cases, I also try some wrong username & accessKey combinations, it just tells me `Starting browser iPhone 6 (ios 6.0) on BrowserStack` as also.

How can I debug this? My karma.conf.js is here:https://gist.github.com/klamtlne/5e18bee9d3090d685c76

Comment: can you post your karma.conf file

Comment: seems like your test cases are not getting executed at all . are you sure your test cases start with this format `'test/*.spec.js'` ? . Can you post your test case and the console logs as well ?